# Model validation in Django 1.1

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm using Django 1.1  I would like to perform validation on a model; specifically, check the extension of a file in a FileField. I can do the extension check fine, but I don't know how to show an error in the admin panel if it's the wrong extension; similar to when you forget to fill in a required field.

I've tried 2 ways to do it.

- Make a custom field, based on a filefield and do the validation its clean() method. I can then raise a ValidationError. This works in Django 1.2, but not in 1.1.
- Overwrite the save() method of the model. I'm unable to throw a ValidationError here though since it just shows a general error page (which regular users won't see) and not a useful message in the admin.

Is there any way I can do what I want in Django 1.1?

Comment: Please upgrade when possible :)

Answer (score 3):

Django 1.1 doesn't have model validation. The only other place to do validation is on the form - all you have to do is define a custom modelform with your clean method and then tell the admin to use it.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_myfilefield(self):
        ... do validation or raise forms.ValidationError('message')

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = MyModel
    form = MyForm
```

Note that just checking the extension is not enough to be sure you're getting the file type you expect.

Comment: I must still be doing something wrong. There already was a 'MyModel'Admin defined so I added the extra code. Then I put my clean method in a MyModelForm class. However, I can't see the model in the admin panel; it's just not visible somehow.